# Load a new header file while kernel module already loaded in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i'm trying to modify the behaviour of an already loaded kernel module by adding functionalities at runtime.
The scenario is:

1. Load kernel module intercepting some syscall (at this point my module act as some king of proxy)
2. I write a portion of code that implements some kind of syscall hook in an external file
3. I want that the loaded kernel module can adapt itself to implement the syscall hook without unloading the module itself (at this point the module use that syscall implementation and not act as "proxy" for the syscall)

How can i achieve this? The perfect way would be without creating a new module and add the dependency, but actually load the specific implementation as an header file or something like this.

Thanks in andvance

Comment: Your question makes no sense. A "*header file*" is a source file only intended for use during the compilation phase. At runtime, you use executable code, not source code. You cannot "*modify the behaviour*" of existing/loaded code other than what is already coded. Seems like you're trying to circumvent kernel security, or you're oblivious to the need for security.

Comment: i'm actually don't how to explain what i want to do. let me try in a better way. i want to implements the hook of a specific syscall when the module is already loaded in the kernel by adding external source or executable code and i really dont know how i can (and if i really can) do it. I'm searching for suggestion @sawdust

Comment: Source code has to be compiled before running. Are you suggesting to compile the source at the time of module loading? Then you have to consider eBPF. and not C program.

Comment: i want to use insmod to upload the module. At some time i'd like to extend the functionalities of the main module using some king of code (as library, as compiled c program) without removing the module - @0andriy

Comment: So the eBPF is the only possibility nowadays to do something like what you are asking for.